# How to select rows in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to create a new dataframe for gender= male , gender is column in train dataset, I want to print all columns and rows where gender = male
[Output of what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40uW6.png)

Answer (score 0):

This return the columns where the gender is male

```
df[df['gender'] == 'male']
```

Answer (score 0):

male_df = df.loc[df['gender'] == 'male']

Comment: This is virtually the same as the already proposed answer.